# (Javascript) How do I have a duplicate entry (item, quantity, price) instead add to the existing quantity?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a simple shopping list app that lists the item you want to buy, the quantity you want to buy, and the expected price that you'll pay for each (for now its entered in manually). Then it organizes all your entries in a table.

The issue I'm running into is when a duplicate item is about to be added. I would like an otherwise duplicate item in the list to be instead combined into the existing item with the quantity updated.

So if "Cereal, 10, 4.99" is submitted and a "Cereal, 15, 5.99" already exists, then instead of a new entry being created the existing entry is updated to be

"Cereal, 25, 5.99" (I'll figure out how to average the prices later.)

This was my best attempt but it doesn't work:

```
for (var i=0; i<itemArray.length; i++) {
    if (itemArray[i] === newItemEntry) {
      quantityArray[i] = quantityArray[i] + newQuantityEntry;
    } else {
        itemArray.push(newItemEntry);
        quantityArray.push(newQuantityEntry);
        expectedPriceForEachArray.push(newExpectedPriceForEachEntry);
    }
};
```

My working HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script src="script.js"></script>

<body>
    <h1>
        Enter an item, quantity, and the price you're expecting to pay.
    </h1>
    Item:<br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="ketchup" id="itemForm">
    <br>
    <br> Quantity:
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="number" placeholder="25" id="quantityForm">
    <br>
    <br> Expected Price for Each:<br>
    <br>
    <input type="number" placeholder="2.99" id="expectedPriceForEachForm">
    <br>
    <br>

    <button onclick="addToListOfEntries()">Add this entry to the list</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <table id="myEntries" border='1' width='400'>
        <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Expected Price For Each</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

My working Javascript:

```
var itemArray = []
var quantityArray = []
var expectedPriceForEachArray = []

function addToListOfEntries () {
  var table = document.getElementById("myEntries");
  var row = table.insertRow();
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var newItemEntry = document.getElementById("itemForm").value
  var newQuantityEntry = document.getElementById("quantityForm").value
  var newExpectedPriceforEachEntry = document.getElementById("expectedPriceForEachForm").value

  itemArray.push(newItemEntry);
  quantityArray.push(newQuantityEntry);
  expectedPriceForEachArray.push(newExpectedPriceforEachEntry);

  for(var i=0; i<itemArray.length;i++)
  {
    cell1.innerHTML = itemArray[i];
    cell2.setAttribute('style', 'text-align: right;');
    cell2.innerHTML = quantityArray[i];
    cell3.setAttribute('style', 'text-align: right;');
    cell3.innerHTML = expectedPriceForEachArray[i] + " USD";
  }
}
```

```js
var itemArray = []
var quantityArray = []
var expectedPriceForEachArray = []

function addToListOfEntries () {
  var table = document.getElementById("myEntries");
  var row = table.insertRow();
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var newItemEntry = document.getElementById("itemForm").value
  var newQuantityEntry = document.getElementById("quantityForm").value
  var newExpectedPriceforEachEntry = document.getElementById("expectedPriceForEachForm").value

  itemArray.push(newItemEntry);
  quantityArray.push(newQuantityEntry);
  expectedPriceForEachArray.push(newExpectedPriceforEachEntry);

  for(var i=0; i<itemArray.length;i++)
  {
    cell1.innerHTML = itemArray[i];
    cell2.setAttribute('style', 'text-align: right;');
    cell2.innerHTML = quantityArray[i];
    cell3.setAttribute('style', 'text-align: right;');
    cell3.innerHTML = expectedPriceForEachArray[i] + " USD";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script src="script.js"></script>

<body>
    <h1>
        Enter an item, quantity, and the price you're expecting to pay.
    </h1>
    Item:<br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="ketchup" id="itemForm">
    <br>
    <br> Quantity:
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="number" placeholder="25" id="quantityForm">
    <br>
    <br> Expected Price for Each:<br>
    <br>
    <input type="number" placeholder="2.99" id="expectedPriceForEachForm">
    <br>
    <br>

    <button onclick="addToListOfEntries()">Add this entry to the list</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <table id="myEntries" border='1' width='400'>
        <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Expected Price For Each</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use JavaScript's `includes` and `indexOf` methods to check whether item already exists and at what index to add sums.

Comment: I would rather use just one array representing the "cart" where you would place the new items. 
`var cart = [{ item: 'Cereal', unitPrice: 5.9, quantity: 15}]` then you can use the [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function to search for existing items. When it's not there you `push` a new entry, else just update the quantity property (you could use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Javascript objects to record your entries rather than three different arrays:

```
// a sample item: 
var item = {
   name: "something",
   quantity: 5,
   price: 4.99
};

// a sample cart: 
var cartItems = [
    {name: "Tomato", quantity: 5, price: 2.99},
    {name: "Potato", quantity: 6, price: 5.99}
];

// Now you can easily add them in the HTML:
for(var i=0; i<cartItems.length;i++)
{
    cell1.innerHTML = cartItems[i].name;
    cell2.setAttribute('style', 'text-align: right;');
    cell2.innerHTML = cartItems[i].quantity;
    cell3.setAttribute('style', 'text-align: right;');
    cell3.innerHTML = cartItems[i].price + " USD";
}

// And you can also comapare them like this: 
  for (var i=0; i < cartItems.length; i++) {
      if (itemArray[i].name === newItemEntry) {
        cartItems[i].quantity += newQuantityEntry; // we add the quantity to the existing.
        cartItems[i].price = (cartItems[i].price + newExpectedPriceForEachEntry) / 2; // We average the price.
      } else {
          // else you push that item as a new object: 
          cartItems.push({
               name: newItemEntry,
               quantity: newQuantityEntry,
               price: newExpectedPriceForEachEntry
          });
      }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

would you please check the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script type="text/javascript">
var itemArray = []
var quantityArray = []
var expectedPriceForEachArray = []

function addToListOfEntries () {
  var table = document.getElementById("myEntries");
  while(table.rows.length > 1) {
    table.deleteRow(1);
  }
  var newItemEntry = document.getElementById("itemForm").value
  var newQuantityEntry = document.getElementById("quantityForm").value
  var newExpectedPriceforEachEntry = document.getElementById("expectedPriceForEachForm").value

  var index = itemArray.indexOf(newItemEntry);

  if( index > -1 ) {
      quantityArray[index] = Number(quantityArray[index]) + Number(newQuantityEntry);
      expectedPriceForEachArray[index] = Number(expectedPriceForEachArray[index]) + Number(newExpectedPriceforEachEntry);
  }else{
        itemArray.push(newItemEntry);
        quantityArray.push(newQuantityEntry);
        expectedPriceForEachArray.push(newExpectedPriceforEachEntry);
  }
  for(var i=0; i<itemArray.length;i++)
  {
    var row = table.insertRow();
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    cell1.innerHTML = itemArray[i];
    cell2.setAttribute('style', 'text-align: right;');
    cell2.innerHTML = quantityArray[i];
    cell3.setAttribute('style', 'text-align: right;');
    cell3.innerHTML = expectedPriceForEachArray[i] + " USD";
  }
}   
</script>

<body>
    <h1>
        Enter an item, quantity, and the price you're expecting to pay.
    </h1>
    Item:<br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="ketchup" id="itemForm">
    <br>
    <br> Quantity:
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="number" placeholder="25" id="quantityForm">
    <br>
    <br> Expected Price for Each:<br>
    <br>
    <input type="number" placeholder="2.99" id="expectedPriceForEachForm">
    <br>
    <br>

    <button onclick="addToListOfEntries()">Add this entry to the list</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <table id="myEntries" border='1' width='400'>
        <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Expected Price For Each</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

@dlac is right, but in the last step I would work with the index, since you have to update the table, too.

```js
var items = [];

function addNewItem()
{
  var table = document.getElementById("myEntries");
  var row = table.insertRow();
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var item = 
    {
      name : document.getElementById("itemForm").value,
      quantity: parseInt(document.getElementById("quantityForm").value),
      price : parseInt(document.getElementById("expectedPriceForEachForm").value)
      
    };
    
  items.push( item );
  
  cell1.innerHTML = item.name;
  cell2.setAttribute('style', 'text-align: right;');
  cell2.innerHTML = item.quantity;
  cell3.setAttribute('style', 'text-align: right;');
  cell3.innerHTML = item.price + " USD";
  
}

function updateItem(item)
{
  var idx = items.indexOf(item);
  items[idx].price +=  parseInt(document.getElementById("expectedPriceForEachForm").value);
  items[idx].quantity +=  parseInt(document.getElementById("quantityForm").value);
              document.getElementById("myEntries").rows[idx+1].cells[2].innerHTML = items[idx].price + " USD";
              document.getElementById("myEntries").rows[idx+1].cells[1].innerHTML = items[idx].quantity;
  
}

function addToListOfEntries () {
  
  var possibleUpdateItem = items.find(function(element) {
    return element.name == document.getElementById("itemForm").value;
  });
  
  if(possibleUpdateItem)
  {
    updateItem(possibleUpdateItem); 
  }else
  {
    addNewItem();
  }
  
}
```

```html
    <h1>
        Enter an item, quantity, and the price you're expecting to pay.
    </h1>
    Item:<br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="ketchup" id="itemForm">
    <br>
    <br> Quantity:
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="number" placeholder="25" id="quantityForm">
    <br>
    <br> Expected Price for Each:<br>
    <br>
    <input type="number" placeholder="2.99" id="expectedPriceForEachForm">
    <br>
    <br>

    <button onclick="addToListOfEntries()">Add this entry to the list</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <table id="myEntries" border='1' width='400'>
        <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Expected Price For Each</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
```